# Angular binding does not happens

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to Angular. I was trying out some demo programs and got a problem.

Here is my HTML code. I am using a controller named `domController`, and app `myDom`.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src = "dom.js"></script>
    <title>Angular Dom Management</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-app="myDom" ng-controller="domController">
        <input type="textbox" ng-model="first_name"></input>
        <input type="textbox" ng-model="last_name"></input>
        <span>{{myName}}</span>
    </div>

    </div>

</body>
<script type="text/javascript">

</script>

</html>
```

Here is my controller script written in `dom.js` file.

```
var myDom = angular.module('myDom',[]);
    myDom.controller('domController', ['$scope', function($scope){      
        $scope.first_name = "Rock";
        $scope.last_name = "Star";
        $scope.myName = $scope.first_name +" "+$scope.last_name;
    }]);
```

My problem is when I open this in browser, the binding `{{myName}}` shows correct value as `Rock Star`. But when I change the value in the input field, the values does not change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$scope.myName` is the concatenation of your first and last name *on load* - `myName` isn't a watched value and won't be updated instantly - you need to add the `watch` or the `ngChange` and constantly update.

Solution one: Use the view to concatenate:

```
<span>{{first_name + " " + last_name}}</span>
```

Solution two: Add an `ngChange`

```
$scope.nameUpdated = function() {
    $scope.myName = $scope.first_name +" "+$scope.last_name;
}

<input type="textbox" ng-change="nameUpdated()" ng-model="first_name"></input>
<input type="textbox" ng-change="nameUpdated()" ng-model="last_name"></input>
```

Comment: the ng-change version will not work until a change is done. `$scope.nameUpdated()` should be called one time at initialization. Otherwise good answer

Comment: @floribon I have a doubt, ignore if I am wrong. If we are calling `$scope.nameUpdated()` inside the function, does it fall into a recursive loop?

Comment: @nitroman of course, what I mean is to run the function once in your controller but not inside the function itself. For exemple define the function, then execute it once, the other executions will be done by `ng-change`

Answer (score 1):

Try this way:

```
$scope.myName = function () {
    return $scope.first_name +" "+$scope.last_name
};
```

HTML:

```
<span>{{myName()}}</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

The expression in your controller

```
$scope.myName = $scope.first_name +" "+$scope.last_name;
```

is not going to update magically when you change `$scope.first_name` or `$scope.last_name` later. In fact it has nothing to do with Angular. You either set up wather manually

```
$scope.$watchGroup(['first_name', 'last_name'], function() {
  $scope.myName = $scope.first_name +" "+$scope.last_name;
});
```

But this so-so solution. I would create a getter, no Angular, just pure JS:

```
Object.defineProperty($scope, 'fullName', {
  get() {
    return $scope.first_name + $scope.last_name;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because you did not change your `$scope.myName` field. It was calculated at start and won't be changed.

Try the following:

```
<body>
    <div ng-app="myDom" ng-controller="domController">
        <input type="textbox" ng-model="first_name"></input>
        <input type="textbox" ng-model="last_name"></input>
        <span>{{first_name + " " + last_name}}</span>
    </div>
</body>
```